# Blank Page after Prepared Statement PHP

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, bindparam

After I used prepared statements to reduce the risk of SQL injection, the button click makes the page blank. I could not find any errors in my code. What is causing the page to go blank and how can I prevent it from happening?

```
if(isset($_POST['desc_btn'])) { 
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($_POST['code_desc']));
    $desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, strip_tags($_POST['description']));

    $code_select =  $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM data WHERE code=?");
    $code_select->bind_param("s", $code);
    $code_select->execute();
    $data = $code_select->get_result();
    $data_user_id = $data['user_id'];

    $data_id = $data['id'];

    if($user_id == $data_user_id  ) {
        $code_select->close();
        $update = $con->prepare("UPDATE data SET description=? WHERE id=?");
        $update->bind_param('s', $desc, $data_id;
        $update->execute();
        $update->close();
    }
}
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Thanks for your help. I am open to any input.

Comment: First of all, you should not use mysqli_real_escape_string, PHP PDO does all the escaping that it needs itself

Comment: The page is supposed to be blank.  You don't echo anything here.

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error on the `$update->bind_param()` line.

The `type` char for `$data_id` and the closing parenthesis were missing.

Change to following code

```
$update->bind_param('si', $desc, $data_id);
```

Comment: Even after I fixed this, the button still leads to a blank page. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

> The error_reporting() function sets the error_reporting directive at
>   runtime. PHP has many levels of errors, using this function sets that
>   level for the duration (runtime) of your script. If the optional level
>   is not set, error_reporting() will just return the current error
>   reporting level.

You should call this function at the beginning of the file.

> Most of E_STRICT errors are evaluated at the compile time thus such
>   errors are not reported in the file where error_reporting is enhanced
>   to include E_STRICT errors (and vice versa).